# JavaScript/Json? - adding json.stringify, dont really know this

Tags: javascript

So, i am running into a issue in my JS file saying:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation

fairly new to JSON stringify too

```js
//                             ||
//making a clicker, issue here \/
function exportSave() {
 var string = '[' ++ JSON.stringify(cookies).innerHTML="cookies" ++ ',' ++ JSON.stringify(cursors).innerHTML="cursors" ++ ',' ++ JSON.stringify(grandmas).innerHTML="grandmas" ++ ',' ++ JSON.stringify(robots).innerHTML="robots" ++ ',' ++ JSON.stringify(farms).innerHTML="farms" ++ ',' ++ JSON.stringify(factories).innerHTML="factories" ++ ',' ++ JSON.stringify(cookieLevel).innerHTML="cookieLevel" ++ ']';
    document.write(string)
 }
  /*output when typing in exportSave(); at console:
  Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation
  */
//some recommended this, also didnt work:
'

function exportSave2() {
 var string = '[' + JSON.stringify(cookies).innerHTML="cookies" + ',' + JSON.stringify(cursors).innerHTML="cursors" + ',' + JSON.stringify(grandmas).innerHTML="grandmas" + ',' + JSON.stringify(robots).innerHTML="robots" + ',' + JSON.stringify(farms).innerHTML="farms" + ',' +
JSON.stringify(factories).innerHTML="factories" + ',' +
JSON.stringify(cookieLevel).innerHTML="cookieLevel" + ']';
 document.write(string)
}
exportSave();
exportSave2();
```

exportSave2(); posts a error saying:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
What i am trying to do is to list a save code to save and load a game. Already did it with localStorage but i want another way.

Comment: `+` is the concatenation operator in JavaScript, not `++`, which, as the error tells you, is the postfix operator.

Comment: `++` operator in `javasacript` is called `increment` operator. Use instead single `+` operator which is for string values called `concatination` operator. In addition there is incorrect syntaxes you have used for assignment. You need to explain what exactly you want to achieve with it, than only SO users will be able to post answer.

Comment: Tried that before incrementing it, didnt work also

Comment: didnt work as in logs error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: `',' + JSON.stringify(farms).innerHTML="farms" + ','` --- what does this expression mean? You have a string concatenate it with... an assignment?

Comment: fairly new to JSON stringify too so, dont know what that means

Comment: Then start from learning what it means. If you don't know what you put in your code - how do you know what to expect from it?

Comment: @Kamal Singh i want to achieve posting the stringifed number

Comment: @zerkms i found this code off another clicker game and decided to try it in mine.

Comment: Try to build your code incrementally (always do that actually). Write a single piece of code that runs. It need not do anything useful yet, it just should run without syntactic errors. Then slowly add more and more logic there, and check that you are on the right way after every tiny change. This would help you avoid the situation when you have a bunch of code that you cannot even understand.

Comment: "i found this code off another clicker game and decided to try it in mine" --- then contact an original developer to explain it for you. Stackoverflow is a communty that helps you with programming not with stealing and adapting someone else's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woah, uncommon, the person that posted the question posts the answer.
I found the right code by doing @zerkms strategy, break it down until it works. then, add the rest. And i did that so, this is what i ended up with:

```js
var string = '[' + JSON.stringify(cookies)  + ',' + JSON.stringify(cursors) + ',' + JSON.stringify(grandmas) + ',' + JSON.stringify(robots) + ',' + JSON.stringify(farms) + ',' + JSON.stringify(factories) + ',' + JSON.stringify(cookieLevel) + ']';
//works with my full main.js
```

So, thanks for helping everyone, and this question has been ANSWERED!

Answer (score 0):

You have written partial code. `JSON.stringify()` is a `jQuery` function to convert `javascript` object as `string`. Read about this at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp). Your sample code is updated below for your reference. After seeing the output you will know what exactly the code was doing from where you took the reference.

```js
function exportSave() {
//In your case these all objects might be populating from some other sources. For convenience I have created custom objects with some dummy data.
var cookies = {id: 10, value: 'Test Cookies'};
var cursors = {name: 'Pointer'};
var grandmas = {name: 'GM'};
var robots = {label: 'My Robot', task: 'Digging Up'};
var farms = {place: 'Near Lake', grows: 'Food'};
var factories = {produces: 'Items'};
var cookieLevel = {level: 1};

    var string = '[' + JSON.stringify(cookies) + ',' + JSON.stringify(cursors) + ',' + JSON.stringify(grandmas) + ',' + JSON.stringify(robots) + ',' + JSON.stringify(farms) + ',' + JSON.stringify(factories) + ',' + JSON.stringify(cookieLevel) + ']';
    document.write(string)
}
exportSave();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```